# How to display the BottomSheetDialogFragment above the BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomsheetdialog

How to display the BottomSheetDialogFragment above the BottomNavigationView.
To be able to interact with the displayed BottomSheetDialogFragment as with a normal BottomSheetDialogFragment. Also, it should always be above the BottomNavigationView.

I've tried every way I can think of to realize this idea, but I can't(

Answer (score 0):

Adding a bottom margin to the main bottom sheet layout might help, try it

Comment: thanks for the help, but it didn't help me.  If it’s not difficult, you can post an example.